# PHP Page not getting root directory

Tags: php, html

I have a page that is in a /restricted directory on my server. I have includes files in a directory /includes . These includes files contain styling, header, nav, footer, etc. My issue is I can't seem to get it to find the includes files from the page in /restricted. Below is some of my code as is in the /restricted directory.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>PRS Network</title>

    <?php include('includes/public_head.php'); ?>

    <!-- Google Analytics Code Goes Below Here -->

    <!-- End Google Analytics Code -->

</head>

<body> <?php include_once("includes/analyticstracking.php") ?>
    <div id="outter">
    <div id="wrapper">

        <?php include('includes/public_header.php'); ?>

        <?php include('includes/main_nav.php'); ?>

        <hr noshade width="97%">

        <?php include('includes/social.php'); ?>
```

I've tried placing "/" in front of includes and it still will not find the includes file. When I try to load the page in a browser this is what I get:

```
Warning: include(includes/public_head.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in .../html/restricted/videoarchive.php on line 12

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'includes/public_head.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in .../html/restricted/videoarchive.php on line 12

Warning: include_once(includes/analyticstracking.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in .../html/restricted/videoarchive.php on line 20

Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'includes/analyticstracking.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in .../html/restricted/videoarchive.php on line 20

Warning: include(includes/public_header.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in .../html/restricted/videoarchive.php on line 24

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'includes/public_header.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in .../html/restricted/videoarchive.php on line 24

Warning: include(includes/main_nav.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in .../html/restricted/videoarchive.php on line 26

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening 'includes/main_nav.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5/lib/php') in .../html/restricted/videoarchive.php on line 26

Warning: include(includes/social.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in .../html/restricted/videoarchive.php on line 30
```

(Note: I've removed some text in the error I receive in the browser. But it looks like it is always looking in the /restricted directory, even when I add "/" before includes.)

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am just guessing since I don't know your file structure, but you are probably looking for `../includes/analyticstracking.php`

Comment: can you show us your file structure ? this is the issue i can see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have folders like this:

```
/path/to/website/
/path/to/website/restricted/
/path/to/website/includes/
```

When you use this within the `restricted` folder:

```
include_once("includes/analyticstracking.php")
```

It's looking for this:

```
/path/to/website/restricted/includes/analyticstracking.php
```

If you prepend a `/`, it's looking for this:

```
/includes/analyticstracking.php
```

Neither of those exist.  You need to traverse up one directly with the `..` folder notation:

```
include_once("../includes/analyticstracking.php")
```

Or, conversely, fully-qualify the path:

```
include_once("/path/to/website/includes/analyticstracking.php")
```

Either way, you need to reference the file relatively from the current working directory of the script, or absolutely from the root of the file system.

Comment: That worked. Could have swore I had tried that, apparently not. I also added `code`<?php

$site_root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>

 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
 <title>PRS Network</title>
 
 <?php include($site_root . '/includes/public_head.php'); ?> `code` which worked as well.

Answer (score 1):

if /restricted and /includes are both on the same level (same directory), then all you need to do is, (When you are inside of /restricted)

call the php constant **DIR**, then wrap it in dirname(**DIR**), so you can get an ABSOLUTE PATH.

```
<?php  include_once dirname(__DIR__).'/includes/blah/blah/blah.php';
```

What you shoudl really do is define a constant like:

```
<?php
 define('ROOT_DIR', __DIR__);
```

save that in a file (CONSTANTS.php) in the ROOT of your directory. then include it in all files, so no matter where you are/ what ever directory your in, you can always call ROOT_DIR to get your directory root, then add on to that with the directory you want.

Comment: Beat me to it. So I'll just up-vote yours. Might also help to have:
`define('INCLUDES_DIR',__DIR__.'/includes');`
(that in the main script)
Then anywhere within the script or includes, even nested 5 levels deep in includes, to include a file you'd use:
`<?php include(INCLUDES_DIR.'/public_head.php'); ?>`
or 
`<?php include_once(INCLUDES_DIR.'/analyticstracking.php'); ?>`
etc

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that includes and restricted are at the same directory level, you need to point one directory up to find them:

instead of:

```
<?php include('includes/public_header.php'); ?>
```

You would use:

```
<?php include('../includes/public_header.php'); ?>
```